# accessing local var value from JS function in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, global-variables, local-variables

After searching for internet and even here for 5 hours, i am still stuck at getting value of a local variable in a function and sending it to PHP.

I have tried different syntaxes but none of them seems to be working. This code below, takes an input field from PHP and assign some value to it (having problem send this value back to PHP)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

//select all the a tag with name equal to modal
$('form[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //Dont go until value is not 7
    console.log('i am Now waiting for input');
    var s = $('#serial').val();
    console.log('searching for ' + s);
    while(s.length != 7) return;


    //When code value reaches 7

    var code = $('#serial').val();
    console.log('Value is reached ' + s);
  });

});
```

### In PHP

```
echo "<script>document.write(code);</script>";

Uncaught ReferenceError: code is not defined
```

please help

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client-side code and server-side code.

Comment: i understand in a way that JS is manipulated client side and PHP on server side. I need to take this variable and rePost it back to php automatically or with a button, thats not the issue, the issue is how do i extract the value of this Local variable..

Comment: Try to replace `var code = ...` by `code = ...` or `document.code = ...` and add `type="text/javascript"` to your script tag.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly still no luck, giving the referenceError

Comment: another thing I forget to mention, make sure your `echo` is printing after you are assigning your javascript variable ... this is not the best way to do things you can also take a look at the ajax approach.

Comment: @digitiZer: Look at the generated HTML source.

Comment: @SLaks in html source it is showing as `Variable is <script>document.write(code);</script>` so it is not giving the value but just the plain code (on page it is blank though)

Comment: There are too many things wrong with your code. If you want to send a value to PHP you'll need to send an ajax request or make the form post the value. What are you trying to achieve on PHP with that value?

Comment: @fbiagi There is a Div residing in index.php which will be shown as popup box with value from the input field. The JS code will be executed when user start typing in input field and div will display when value lenth is 7 and submit button is clicked or input field is blurred and focused on again. well... that div then will take the input field value and run a database query fetching record containing that value in field..

This is what i am trying to acomplish which right now seems impossible to me :(

i have also tried thorugh ajax but it then starts giving **UNKNOWN INDEX**

Comment: The div is an HTML element, is not PHP. You should find out how to post values from a form element, and use the onBeforeSubmit event (or submit on jquery) to validate the length and preventDefault to avoid it. If you don't want to reload the page, use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do somthing like this in javascript when $('#serial') is your input field.

```
$.ajax({'url':'your_php_file_url', 'type':'post', 'data':{'str':$('#serial').val()}}).done(function(data){
console.log(data.code);
});
```

And in php

```
$output = Array('code' => 'not set');
if (isset($_POST['str']))
{
//do your search and assigne value to output
$output['code'] = 'some value';
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

In short - you send your search string via ajax to php and make your searches. Then you echo it out as json, then ajax will read it as an object and you can use those values you want.

Comment: setting ajax inside or outside function and 
the div says `{"code":"not set"}`

Comment: @digitiZer, If you do not send parameter str via post then result is {"code":"not set"}, if you send some data with parameter str then result is {"code":"some value"}. In ajax i set parameter str 'data':{'str':$('#serial').val(), and if you do not have input with id="serial", you will not post str with value.

Comment: Thanks bro, i sorted it out exactly the same way you described here :D a +1 to your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, i have almost tested every possible solution but all in vain... so i am off and try to use some normal method rather than javascript. Thanks for all your answers guys.

Comment: Read the generated Javascript and you'll see why it doesn't make sense.  You need to declare a client-side variable.